# Error API authentication by passing access and secret key in header

Tags: python, api

I am trying to authenticate using API key and Secret but it is showing 403 error. Below is the code

```
headers = {'X-API-KEY': 'someapikey', 'X-API-SECRET': 'somesecretkey'}
url="http://ops.epo.org/rest-services/publisheddata/publication/epodoc/EP1000000/fulltext"
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

The error message is :

```
b'<error><code>403</code><message>This request has been rejected due to the
 violation of Fair Use policy</message><moreInfo>http://www.epo.org/searching
/free/espacenet/fair-use.html</moreInfo>\n\t\t\t\t</error>\n\t\t\t'
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with your headers, you've sent too many requests and got a temporary ban. You have to wait for some time and try again. The correct link to fair use policy is https://www.epo.org/service-support/ordering/fair-use.html

Read the "Automated queries" section and consider adding some throttling to your script.

Comment: I was trying. but it says I can do 4Gb per week.

Comment: @PankajGarg you can contact them by email and maybe they'll help

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try to use REST API and read about throttling. I am new to this.

Comment: Basic throttling is done just by calling time.sleep() between requests